# Help with IF statement in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hoping someone can help!

Getting this error:

> An IF statement is not closed with the required ENDIF statement

My AMPscript as follows:

```
if RowCount(@ InterbankRateRow) == 1 
  then 
     set @ InterbankRate = Field(Row(@ InterbankRateRow, 1), 'Value') 
else 
   set @ InterbankRate = 'no rows returned' 
endif

%%[

  if @quotedInterbankRate < @InterbankRate then
     set @rateMessage = 'Good news, the market rate is now even better!'
     set @rateMessage2 = 'We thought you'd like to know that since you quoted the market rate has improved. Now could be a good time to lock in your transfer.'
  else
     set @rateMessage = 'Still need to transfer funds?'
     set @rateMessage2 = 'Remember the markets are always moving. If you were happy with your quote, lock in your transfer now.'
  endif

]%%
```

Comment: is this the only place you have `IF` statements?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I do have one other IF statement above - does that change things?   if RowCount(@ InterbankRateRow) == 1 then
     set @ InterbankRate = Field(Row(@ InterbankRateRow, 1), 'Value')
  else 
     set @ InterbankRate = 'no rows returned'
  endif

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have opening and closing block tags (`%%[` `]%%`).

There should be no spaces after the `@` in your variable names.

Something like this:

```
%%[

if RowCount(@InterbankRateRow) == 1 then 
    set @InterbankRate = Field(Row(@InterbankRateRow, 1), 'Value') 
else 
    set @ InterbankRate = 'no rows returned' 
endif

]%%
<!-- other HTML --> 
%%[

if @quotedInterbankRate < @InterbankRate then
    set @rateMessage = 'Good news, the market rate is now even better!'
    set @rateMessage2 = 'We thought you'd like to know that since you quoted the market rate has improved. Now could be a good time to lock in your transfer.'
else
    set @rateMessage = 'Still need to transfer funds?'
    set @rateMessage2 = 'Remember the markets are always moving. If you were happy with your quote, lock in your transfer now.'
endif

]%%
```

Answer (score -1):

@Lauren try like this

```
%%[

        if Rowcount(@InterbankRateRow)=1 then

       set @row=Row(@InterbankRateRow,1)
        set @InterbankRate=Field(@row, "Value")


             else
          set @InterbankRate='no rows returned'
          endif
             ]%%
```